# MS Access: Environmental variables in saved import file path

Tags: ms-access, environment-variables

I've tried searching for an answer to this question, but I haven't been able to find something that addresses it specifically. I have a database with a saved file import that will be used by multiple people. I wanted to do something like `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` instead of `C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop` so that the path to desktop can vary as needed. All computers are Windows XP. I would like to avoid vba if possible.

I realize I could store the files on a server to be imported, but the import is slow across the network. If I am incorrect in my assumption and it is not faster to import the file from the desktop, I'll go ahead and make the server side folder instead.

Comment: What type of file is it? And what programming language do you prefer to use instead of VBA? Thanks and regards,

Comment: @Alex Bell - The file being imported is a text file. There is an import spec to set the fields correctly and ideally I was saving the import to automate everything. I was hoping that no vba would be necessary because the only experience I have there is related to forms. I don't know how to write the vba needed to run it as a macro that a user could click on. Sounds like there is no easy way to go about what I want though?

Comment: In your case, it's probably better to place the file on the server (consider the scenario - what if file got changed? Then you will need to replace it in all User's machines). Also, if I remember correctly, import spec can understand UNC (as well as DOS/Win notation) pertinent to network drives, so it would be relatievely easy to set the path. Best regards,

Comment: @Alex Bell - Once the file is loaded into the database, it isn't needed again, so I'm not too worried about the text file being lost (if that's what you mean). I guess I'll just make a folder on the server and do that for simplicity. Thanks for the discussion!

Comment: I would agree with you, especially if this is a one-time operation. Btw, even though a local HDD performance in general is better than network drive due to traffic, but for .txt file of reasonable size if will be enough. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this VBA expression

```
Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop"
```

to get the value of this shell expression

```
%USERPROFILE%\Desktop
```

Comment: Using this would require me to construct a function, correct? A quick search of the site led me [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413308/calling-a-function-from-macro-design-in-access)